# Connect to computer audio source through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I would like to use my computer's audio as a source for an online music streaming project I'm working on. How would I go about, via JavaScript, accessing my computer's audio output/speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup your computer to output its audio to its microphone input and then use the [`getUserMedia` API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) to capture the audio from your "microphone".

Comment: How can one proxy the audio output to an audio input device (microphone)? - this is the challenge.

Comment: An AUX jack with male ends on both sides should do the trick.